Скачивание файлов с портала Битрикс24
Недавно у нас произошёл переезд на коробочную версию битрикс24. Все данные перенеслись нормально, а вот с диском вышла проблема. На диске около 80 гб записей разговоров которые нужно все перекачать. Но при скачивании всей папки портал падает. Если качать по папкам (примерно 3гб в папке) то в процессе загрузки в какой то момент любой браузер выдаёт "ошибка сети", хотя интернет соединение стабильное.
Пробовал разными способами качать, с разных браузеров, но не помогает ничего. Кто может подсказать софт для этой задачи?
